# Множественный UPDATE одим запросом с условием?

Tags: php, sql

Переменная `$seach` содержит `47,21`
Как обновить записи в таблицы `access_folders` где  `user_id` не равен индитификаторам в переменной `$seach`

Набросал такой код, но он обновляет там где `user_id` равен тому что в `$seach`

```
$sql = "UPDATE `access_folders` SET `disallow`=`1` WHERE user_id IN(".$search.") ";
$query = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die("Ошибка: " . mysqli_error($db));
```

Comment: NOT IN обратное условие

Comment: @MykolaVeriga, спасибо. Я не знал об таком.

Comment: @MykolaVeriga, еще раз спасибо. Напишите ответ я галочкой отмечу что он верный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пример:**

```
$db_name = 'database_name';
$host = 'localhost';
$login = 'root';
$password = '1111';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $login, $password);
```

Дальше можно разсмотреть случай с таблицей

```
test

id   value
```

Имеем массив в котором ключ это `id` строки которую нужно изменить, а значение это `value` которое нужно установить в даной строке.

```
$update_values = array(
  2 => 6865,
  3 => 28635,
  45 => 32,
);
```

Запрос который делает `update` многих строк виглядит следующим образом

```
UPDATE mytable SET 
    field_1 = CASE 
      WHEN id = 1 THEN 'value_field_1' 
      WHEN id = 2 THEN 'value_field_2' 
        ELSE 'default_value_field_1' 
      END,
    field_2 = CASE 
      WHEN id = 1 THEN 'value_field_2' 
      WHEN id = 2 THEN 'value_field_2' 
        ELSE 'default_value_field_2' 
      END
WHERE id IN (1,2);
```

Сгенерируем его на PHP

```
  $sql = 'UPDATE test SET value = CASE id ';

  $keys_update_values = array_keys($update_values);
  foreach ($keys_update_values as $id) {
    $sql .= ' WHEN ' . $id . ' THEN :logo_name_' . $id;
  }
  $sql .= ' END WHERE id IN (' . implode($keys_update_values, ',') . ')';

  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

  foreach ($keys_update_values as $id) {
    $sth->bindParam(':logo_name_' . $id, $update_values[$id]);
  }
  $sth->execute();

  $dbh = null;
```